# PHP call overridden child class function from parent class function in a child object

Tags: php, oop, overriding

I have following class structure

```
class A 
{
  function aa(){
   //do something in aa
   $this->ab();
  }

  function ab(){
   //do something in ab
  }
}

Class B extends A
  function ab(){
   //do something else in ab
  }
}

$b = new B();
$b->aa();
```

When I call aa() from the object of class B, how can I override the method ab, to make sure its called from class B?

Comment: its working! preconditions were not being met!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class B -> ab()  called;

```
<?php
    class A 
    {
      function aa(){
       //do something in aa
       $this->ab();
      }

      function ab(){
       //do something in ab
       echo "class A\n";
      }
    }

    Class B extends A { 
      function ab(){
       //do something else in ab
       echo "class B\n";
      }
    }

    $b = new B();
    $b->aa();
```